# Can anyone explain how to remove duplicates in ArrayList using indexOf,lastIndexOf

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this code, I can't understand how the code works, how does it remove duplicates with that indexOf and lastIndexOf?

```
ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
lst.add("ABC");
lst.add("ABC");
lst.add("ABCD");
lst.add("ABCD");
lst.add("ABCE");

System.out.println("Duplicates List "+lst);

Object[] st = lst.toArray();
for (Object s : st) {
    if (lst.indexOf(s) != lst.lastIndexOf(s)) {
        lst.remove(lst.lastIndexOf(s));
    }
}

System.out.println("Distinct List "+lst);
```

Comment: What's the first position of `x`; what's the last position of `x`? Are those the same? If they aren't, remove the element at the later position.

Comment: Yes, if there are duplicates we have two different positions. Just remove one.

Comment: `lst = lst.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Just a note: solving this problem with the index methods will depend on the collection type having a well-formed `equals()` method (indexOf is defined in terms of equals).  In the example given, one can count on `String` to have a good equals method, but for any client supplied or internally written type, the equals method will need to obey the contract for `Object.equals()`.

Comment: another oneliner not so good looking can be `lst = new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet(lst));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does it remove duplicates with that indexOf and lastIndexOf?

```
if (lst.indexOf(s) != lst.lastIndexOf(s))
```

The code above takes the index of the first occurrence of `s`(if it exists otherwise `-1`) within the list and also takes the index of the last occurrence of `s` (if it exists otherwise `-1`) within the list, if both of the indices are the *same* then there is *no* duplicate and if they are *not* the *same* then we've found a duplicate thus it gets removed from the list.

From the code you're currently working on, we can confirm that the string `"ABC"` appears twice within the collection, one at index `0` and the other at index `1` thus when this is checked by the `if` statement we can guarantee that control will go inside the `if` statement because they're *not* the same indices(meaning there are *at least* two occurrences of the string `s`), likewise the string `"ABCD"` appears twice within the list at index `1` and `2`(note by this time the last occurrence of `"ABC"` is already removed from the list hence `"ABCD"` takes the slot of index `1` due to the nature of a list resizing itself) meaning control will once again go inside the `if` block because they're *not* the same indices.

Eventually, the last occurrence of `s` will be removed from the list and the same procedure is repeated for each iteration of the loop.

There are more efficient ways in which you can [**remove duplicates from a list**](http://www.baeldung.com/java-remove-duplicates-from-list), and you should look into it as it can improve performance time.

Comment: Just finished the whole project.. took me like 10+ hours, I'm happy :)

Answer (score 1):

Try throwing a few more print statements in there, I think you'll be able to see for yourself!

```
    for (Object s : st) {
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(lst.indexOf(s));
        System.out.println(lst.lastIndexOf(s));

        if (lst.indexOf(s) != lst.lastIndexOf(s)) {
            lst.remove(lst.lastIndexOf(s));
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can ask to make additional logging in his code in comment also. This is *not* an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is a pretty clunky (i.e. inefficient) way to do it<sup>1</sup>.

How does it work?

Well this predicate:

```
  lst.indexOf(s) != lst.lastIndexOf(s)
```

is testing to see if there are two (or more) instances of `s` in the list.  The logic is that if the position of the first `s` and the last `s` in the list are different, then there must be *at least* two of them.  Then we remove the last instance.

Since we do this for every string in the original list, if there are M instances of a given string in the list, that test will be performed M times for that string, and will succeed M - 1 times and hence remove M - 1 of those instances.  At the end, you are left with just one instance of each distinct string; i.e. no duplicates.

---

1 - It is `O(N^2)` and it is possible to eliminate duplicates in `O(N)` with `O(N)` temporary space.  The general approach is as follows:

1. Create a temporary array to hold the list content, and a `HashSet`.
2. For each `s` in the original list:

   - If `s` is not in the set:

     - add it to the set, and
     - add it to the temporary array.
3. Clear the original list.
4. Add back all elements in the temporary array.

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thx Stephen